# Only office PHP not view or edit file

Tags: php, onlyoffice

I try to use onlyoffice with PHP example API.

I follow this [guide](https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/example/php) to install.

I succeed install document server in address: http://192.168.131.132, here is image of document server:

[image]

Then I download PHP code in same server with document server (different port: port 81).

I change config.php like this:

[image]

It show me the GUI like this:

[image]

I can upload my document to server, like this:

[image]

But I can't view or edit my office file. This is error like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding one more GLOBAL to the config.php:

```
$GLOBALS['EXAMPLE_URL'] = "http://192.168.131.132:81/PHP%20Example/";
```

If that doesn't help make sure that the permissions are set correctly for the folder with PHP Example.
The error couldn't be saved is described [here](https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/troubleshooting#error0)

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. I have a question. Because I install document server and PHP example on same server. So I must change apache port = 81 (Nginx install default = 80). So I config.php, parameter documentserver=192.168.131.132:81 or only 192.168.131.132

Comment: And. I use only onlyoffice not connect owncloud or nextcloud. It is ok?